# Why is $\frac{1}{\log(2x)}=\frac{1}{\log(x)}-\frac{\log 2}{\log^2(x)}+O\left ( \frac{1}{\log^3(x)} \right )$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

[The Development of Prime Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540662898)  on page 237, it says that
$$
\frac{1}{\log(2x)}=\frac{1}{\log(x)}-\frac{\log 2}{\log^2(x)}+O\left ( \frac{1}{\log^3(x)} \right )
$$
At first I thought it was an expansion of $(\log(2x))^{-1}$, but WolframAlpha doesn't mention that. How did the author come to this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expansion of [$\frac{1}{x+a}$ at $x=\infty$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+order+laurent+expansion+of+1%2F(x%2Ba)+at+x%3Dinfinity)

Then plug $x\rightarrow \log(x)$ and $a\rightarrow\log 2$

Comment: This is smart, but "around x" what exactly? WA shows that it's around $a=0$, and the error term differs from our equation.

Comment: You are right. I corrected it again. Hope it is OK this time.